# yii Relational Active Record

Tags: php, yii, foreign-key-relationship

I have a situation here
there are two models User,Posts
Now I want to list those posts posted by user whose userType=1
Is this possible by tweaking the relations among User & Posts or by adding any kind of scopes?

The relations which I've now

```
User
'Posts' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Post', 'userId'),

Posts
'User' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'userId'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with named scopes or with relations. For example you could define your relation like this:

```
'Posts' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Post', 'userId', 'condition' => 't.userType=1')
```

About "Named Scopes" read here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes

Comment: Nope this is not a working solution. I think this relation needs to be tweaked
'User' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'userId'),

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak the relation definition by adding your filter as a named scope on the fly, like this:

```
    class User extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'Posts'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Post', 'userId',
                'with'=>array(
                    'User'=>array(
                        'scopes'=> array(
                            'userType' => 1,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

more info can be found on Yii guide for [relational-query-with-named-scopes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-named-scopes)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is called a relational ActiveRecord query. The documentation [states](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#disambiguating-column-names):

> In relational AR query, the alias name for the primary table is fixed
>   as t, while the alias name for a relational table is the same as the
>   corresponding relation name by default. For example, in the following
>   statement, the alias name for Post and Comment is t and comments,
>   respectively.

So what you need to do here is:

```
$posts = Posts::model()->findAll('user.userType = 1');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to use defaultScope or something such that everytime I query Posts this search condition is applied by default